# In swiftUI is it possible to add a new view onto the screen with a button?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

Every time I Tap the button I would like a new cardView to appear. I am wondering if this is possible in swiftUI and if so what action I would need to do it. It would be even better if I am able to pass some parameters in to the cardView struct but any help would be great!

````
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                TextButton(action: {print("Button tapped")}, text: "new card")
                CardView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1568627506, blue: 0.07450980693, alpha: 1)))
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100 * 1.618)
                .cornerRadius(16)
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)).opacity(0.1), radius: 1, x: 0, y: 1)
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)).opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)

            VStack {
                Text("Card")
                    .font(.system(size: 10) )
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .bold()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct TextButton: View {
    let action: () -> Void
    let text: String

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action, label: {
            Text(text)
                .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                .padding(.vertical, 16)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(.infinity)
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)).opacity(0.1), radius: 1, x: 0, y: 1)
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)).opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
        })
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SwiftUI, the View reflects the State data, so you don't modify the View directly, but rather modify the State data, and build the View based on the State. This is a core principle behind SwiftUI, and it allows you to separate the View concerns from the data that drives it (ViewModel in some lingo).

So, let's assume that we have a data model for a `Card` (make it conform to `Identifiable` - this will be needed later):

```
struct Card: Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  let name: String
}
```

And let's define an array of cards as a state variable in your View:

```
@State private var cards: [Card] = [Card(name: "foo")]
```

Then the body could display these cards with a `ForEach` or in a `List` view:

```
var body = some View {
  VStack() {
    Button("Add Card") {
       self.cards.append(Card(name: "I'm an added card"))
    }
    ForEach(cards) { card in
       CardView(for: card) // if your CardView had parameters
    }
  }
}
```

What happens is that the closure for the button adds a new `Card` instance to the `cards` state variable. That's it. It doesn't change anything in the View directly. The View sees the change (that's what SwiftUI does behind the scenes) and re-renders itself.

The reason you needed a `Card` to conform to `Identifiable` was to let the `ForEach` know how to uniquely identify each card. Without conforming to identifiable, you could use a key path like so:

```
ForEach(cards) { card in
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you have provided a very clear and coherent explanation. Amazing stuff. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var cards: [CardView] = [CardView()]



    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextButton(action: {
                print("Button tapped")
                self.cards.append(CardView())

            }, text: "new card")
            ZStack {
                ForEach(cards, id: \.self) { card in
                    card
                        .rotationEffect(card.angle)

                }

            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView: View, Hashable, Identifiable {

    var id = UUID()

    var angle : Angle {
        let angle = Angle(degrees: Double.random(in: 0...30))
        print(angle.degrees)
        return angle
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1568627506, blue: 0.07450980693, alpha: 1)))
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100 * 1.618)
                .cornerRadius(16)
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)).opacity(0.1), radius: 1, x: 0, y: 1)
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)).opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)

            VStack {
                Text("Card \(angle.degrees)")
                    .font(.system(size: 10) )
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .bold()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct TextButton: View {
    let action: () -> Void
    let text: String

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action, label: {
            Text(text)
                .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                .padding(.vertical, 16)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(.infinity)
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)).opacity(0.1), radius: 1, x: 0, y: 1)
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)).opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
        })
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]